# Wrapping dynamically added child elements in my slot

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-render-function

If i have a component with a single slot and instead of just rendering all of it's children I want to wrap each element, I do something like this:

```
Vue.component('MyElement', {
  render: function(createElement){
      for (let i = 0; i < this.$slots.default.length; i++) {
      //create a wrapper element
      let wrappedElement = createElement("div", {}, this.$slots.default[i]);
      // replace the current element in this slot, with the wrapped element
      this.$slots.default[i] = wrappedElement;
    }

    return createElement("div", this.$slots.default);
  }
}
```

Used like this:

```
<MyElement ref="myElement">
  <p>Item 1</p>
  <p>Item 2</p>
</MyElement>
```

Which ends up looking like this

```
<div>
  <div>
    <p>Item 1</p>
  </div>
  <div>
     <p>Item 2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Up to this point everything is great.

Now when I'd like to insert another `<p>` element into  `<MyElement>` using

```
// get reference to <MyElement>
const myElement = this.$refs["myElement"];
// create a new element
var newElement = document.createElement("div");
newElement.innerText = "Hiya";
myElement .$el.appendChild(newElement);
```

The new element won't get wrapped, because render is not invoked again, how can I take full control of rendering for each child in my slot? or is there a better when to append children programatically into a component?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you could consider creating a `component` for the Items. So that when you want to add a new item, you could just create a `method` which will invoke the item component.

I made a Code Snippet for this example.

```js
Vue.component('MyElement', {
  template: '#element-container',
});

Vue.component('MyElementItem', {
  template: '#element-item',
  props: {
    innerText: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      items: ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3'],
    }
  },
  method: {
    // you can add a method that will add more items, then the MyElementItem component will be invoked.
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <my-element>
    <my-element-item v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index" :inner-text="item" />
  </my-element>
</div>

<script type="text/x-template" id="element-container">
  <div>
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-template" id="element-item">
  <div>
    <p>{{ innerText }}</p>
  </div>
</script>
```